# What is the difference between Amazon managed Blockchain and Amazon Blockchain Templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, blockchain, hyperledger, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am a beginner in Blockchain and cloud and trying to setup a a hyperledger fabric environment on cloud, because I was facing some issues installing it in my pc. I came across these two option on amazon cloud. One was Amazon Managed Blockchain, and the second was AWS blockchain templates. I can't understand which one to go with. Any guidance with explanation is most welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon managed Blockchain and Amazon Blockchain Templates both are services provided by Amazon. Both have distinct use cases, basically Amazon managed Blockchain is premium Blockchain platform used for deploying production level application whereas Amazon Blockchain Templates is a free tier blockchain service provided by Amazon for developing Blockchain Application.

Amazon Blockchain Template provide a single instance for testing our blockchain project.
Amazon Managed Blockchain being premium service provide as many instance for the deployment.

Edit:
For further detail check this link:
    [Blockchain on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/)

Answer (score 1):

Few more things about amazon managed blockchain is that.

Amazon Managed Blockchain manages Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority (CA) and peer nodes. Amazon Managed Blockchain also creates and manages an Ordering Service for each network. At this stage is Amazon Managed Blockchain in Preview and only for Hyperledger Fabric 1.2. You have to apply for the access. Here is the link to apply for the access[[Click Here]](https://pages.awscloud.com/AmazonManagedBlockchain-preview.html#).

You may also see some limitations highlighted by AWS.

```
Availability is limited to us-east-1.
Hyperledger Fabric is the only supported blockchain framework.
The maximum number of networks per AWS account is 1.
The maximum number of networks that an AWS account can be a member of is 1.
The maximum number of members per network is 5.
The maximum number of peer nodes per member is 1.
Peer nodes are limited to the bc.t3.small instance type.
```

[Known-limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/known-issues-limits.html)
Here is the [Complete tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html) to configure hyperledger fabric network on AWS. You can also configure the network directly from [managedblockchain dashborad](https://console.aws.amazon.com/managedblockchain/home?region=us-east-1#firstRun) from AWS console.